# Por qué da fallo el set (stl)

Tags: c++

En mi código estoy haciendo un grafo donde voy guardando estados y tengo que, como es logico, interconectarlos todos. Ya he repetido el código como 4 veces y siempre me da el mismo error. El codigo es el siguiente:

grafo.hpp

```
#ifndef _boii_


#define _boii_

#include <set>
#include "state.hpp"
using namespace std;
class grafo{
    private:

    set<state> my_states;



    public:
    grafo();
    ~grafo();
    void set_states(int i);

};




#endif
```

grafo.cpp

```
#include "grafo.hpp"


grafo::grafo(){}

grafo::~grafo(){}


void grafo::set_states(int i){
    state a;
    a.set_id(i);
    my_states.insert(a);

}
```

y nodo.hpp

```
#ifndef _qwerty_

 #define _qwerty_


#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


  using namespace std;
class state{

private:

int id;
bool acepted;



public:

state();
~state();
int get_id();
bool get_acpt();

void set_id(int i);
void set_acpt(bool i);

 int operator < (const state& a);

  };



 #endif
```

del objeto nodo solo mostrare el operator, ya que es donde esta dando el error, y ademas que el resto de librerias son simples sets y gets.
el perator < seria :

```
int state::operator < (const state& a){
    if(id < a.id){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Por ultimo el error que me sale siempre es este :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:63:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/set:60,
                 from grafo.hpp:6,
                 from grafo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = state]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:1324:11:   required from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(const key_type&) [with _Key = state; _Val = state; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<state>; _Compare = std::less<state>; _Alloc = std::allocator<state>; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = state]’  


/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:1377:47:   required from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val>, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = state; _Val = state; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<state>; _Compare = std::less<state>; _Alloc = std::allocator<state>]’


/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:463:29:   required from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = state; _Compare = std::less<state>; _Alloc = std::allocator<state>; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<state>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = state]’
grafo.cpp:12:23:   required from here


/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: error: passing ‘const state’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int state::operator<(const state&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^

state.cpp:26:38: error: no ‘int state::operator<(const state&)’ member function declared in class ‘state’
 int state::operator < (const state& a){
                                      ^
```

Realmente agradeceria cualquier ayuda,y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia, en `nodo.h`

```
int operator < (const state& a);
```

por

```
int operator < (const state& a) const;
```

y, en tu `nodo.cpp`

```
int state::operator < (const state& a) {
```

por

```
int state::operator < (const state& a) const {
```

Fíjate que el único cambio es añadir `const` al final de la declaración, justo después del paréntesis de cerrar ( `)` ).

El error es debido a que los objetos de un `std::set< >` son **inmutables** por naturaleza. Internamente, sus elementos se ordenan **al insertarlos**; si una operación posterior los modificara ... pues entonces el orden podría variar, lo cual implica que habría que volver a ordenarlos.

Por esa *inmutabilidad*, las operaciones de comparación al insertar un elemento se realizan sobre tipos constantes ( `const TIPO x` ). Y tu has declarado tu `operator<( )` como **no-constante** ( le falta al `const` ).

**Nota**: como indican en los comentarior, el uso de `using namespace std;` en el ámbito global es una mala práctica ... deberías de acostumbrarte a no usarlo. Puede parecer mas *engorroso* por tener que escribir mas ... pero a la larga, saldrás muy beneficiado, y te puedes ahorrar problemas bastante difíciles de localizar/solucionar :-)

Comment: Comenta lo de evitar `using namespace std` en archivos de cabecera, y la respuesta será perfecta.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Mira que eres *mijitas* tú tambien :-p

Comment: Me sorprende que te acabes de enterar @Trauma

Comment: Es que es correcto:

Regla Misra C++ 2008: *7-3-4: using-directives shall not be used*